# Using Redis.pm pipeline in perl

Tags: perl, redis, pipeline

My attempt to Redis pipeline in perl, using Redis.pm, Is this correct approach? Snipped of code below:

```
...
my $redis = Redis->new(server => '127.0.0.1:6379', reconnect => 60);
foreach my $key (keys %hval) {
    my $ok = $redis->zadd($key, $hval{ $key }, &process); 
}

sub process {
    my ($reply, $error) = @_;
    my $cr = sub {
        my ($r, $e) = @_;
        if ($e) {
            warn Dumper('Redis pipelining crapped out', $e);
        {
    }
}
```

Have you tried this before? I looked around but could not found any suitable example, Please let me know. I am using all required module and this code is for here only. Actual code is much complex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JasonGray forgot to use keys. Its just an hash in example. My question is geared towards understanding pipeline in perl.

Comment: Don't you need a ` \ ` in front of `\&process` in the `zadd()` so you are passing a reference to the subroutine instead of calling it?  Fixed line: `my $ok = $redis->zadd($key, $hval{ $key }, \&process);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
use Redis;

my $redis = Redis->new(server => '127.0.0.1:6379', reconnect => 60);
my %hval = ( 'foo', 1, 'bar', 2, 'foobar', 3 );

foreach my $key (keys %hval) {
    my $ok = $redis->zadd("myzset", $hval{ $key }, $key, sub {
        my ($reply, $error) = @_;
        print "Returned $reply with error = [$error]\n" ;
    });
}
print "Waiting replies ...\n";
$redis->wait_all_responses;
```

Please note that:

- a wait_all_responses clause is required to put a synchronization point with the server.
- zadd requires 3 parameters (zset name, score, key) in that order

Comment: Thanks you. I did exactly same way. Though late, your answer matches mine and answer accepted.

Comment: So is my understanding that if you call the redis command but provide the callback function, then the commands are not sent to the redis server until wait_all_responses is called?